# lambda expression conversion

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a function written using new standard(C++ 0x) back to previous standard

How can I convert the following line

```
typedef std::vector<value3 const*> passmem;
pasmem pm; // neighborhood sequence
 std::for_each(pm.begin(), pm.end(), [&] (value3 const* x)
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some code.

Comment: As well as a description of what you want the code converted to.

Comment: You should add the body of the function, as depending on what the body of the function is, the generated code might differ.

Comment: If you can use new compiler, you should use it!

Answer (score 4):

Just convert the lambda expression into a named function and pass it as a parameter to for_each. Alternatively just do the function of your lambda function inline like:

```
   for (pasmem::iterator it=pm.begin(); it != pm.end(); ++it) {
      // Do the lambda functionality with *it
   }
```

Comment: I guess you meant `it != pm.end();` rather than `*it != pm.end()`.  `++it` is widely considered good general practice too - can be more efficient for certain iterators, though rarely actually makes a meaningful difference.

Comment: `pm` represents an instance, you cannot extract a type member from an instance, but rather need the type (or a typedef alias): `for (passmem::iterator it = pm.begin()...`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(passmem::const_iterator i = pm.begin(); i != pm.end(); ++i)
{
   const value3* x = *i;
   // same as in lambda
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic rules for processing a lambda require creating a function object that offers  `operator()` with the same signature as the lambda. For each one of the captured fields, you will need to add a member to the functor and initialize it in construction. In your particular case that would be by *reference* or *const reference*, depending on where your lambda is being defined and the types involved.

If, for a non-trivial, the lambda was accumulating the value of each element in the vector into a local variable, and (assuming that `value3` has the appropriate operators):

```
struct accumulator__ {
    value3 & v_;
    accumulator__( value3 & v ) : v_(v) {}

    void                                   // for_each ignores the return value
    operator()( value3 const * p ) {       // same argument as lambda
       v_ += *p;
    }
};
```

If the lambda was defined as a member function, and it accessed any member of the class, then things would become a little trickier, but you would basically have to create the *closure* of all accessed fields manually (i.e. adding [`const`] references of all the accessed members. Real lambdas (I believe) only capture `this` but in the refactoring you 
may loose access rights to the members of the class.

Answer (score 0):

At first, @george272 has the solution (although I'd call iterator `(c)it` and not `i`).

Going back to your original code, **you should not** (almost) **ever use for_each in C++11**.

Here is why:

```
typedef std::vector<value3 const*> passmem;
pasmem pm; // neighborhood sequence
for(auto x : pm)
{ 
  // do your stuff as normal but with less typing ;)
}
```